# How to add separate column in header for vertical scrolling in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid

Row columns are not properly aligned with header columns when jqgrid having morethan 50 records.

How to add extra column in header for vertical scrolling in jqgrid like below image.

**Example:** [Display Extra column for vertical scrolling in jqgrid.](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

[image: jqgrid column for scrolling]

In my jqgrid there is no separate column for vertical scrolling, the row and header columns are changed when headers are more than 10.

Below is the image of jqgrid having no header column for vertical scrolling.
[image: jqgrid header columns not properly aligned with row columns]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding `padding-right: 20px;` in **ui.jqgrid.css** file at css class `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable` header with empty column is displayed along with vertical scrolling.

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable {table-layout:fixed;margin:0; padding-right: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

with jqGrid version 4.1.1 you can Add an extra value to your columns:

```
colNames:['ID',
              'Etat',
              'Date',
              'Fournisseur<br/>Commande',
              'Contenu',''],
```

then add in the blank column definition:

```
  colModel:[
      {name:'ID',index:'ID',hidden:true,width:70,align:'center',sorttype: 'int'},
      {name:'ETAT',index:'ETAT',width:150,align:'center'},
      {name:'DATE',index:'DATE',width:150,align:'center',title: false},
      {name:'FOURNISSEUR_CMD',index:'FOURNISSEUR_CMD',width:200,align:'center',title: false},
      {name:'CONTENU',index:'CONTENU',width:200,align:'center',title: false},
 { name: "empty1", width: 10, sortable: false, hidedlg: true, search: false, resizable: false, fixed: true }     
    ],
```

Then you should get output like [this example](http://jsbin.com/soroto/2/edit)

With jqGrid version 4.6.0 you will have the column by default like this [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/yNw3C/9679/)

Comment: It shows [extra column with empty data](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1414204394041)

Comment: it works fine [here](http://jsbin.com/soroto/2/) and i'm using jqGrid-4.1.1 which version of jqGrid you are using ?

Comment: I am using jqgrid 4.5.2. The [link you posted in answer](http://jsbin.com/soroto/2/edit) works but when use these code in my jqgrid it is showing extra column with empty data.

Comment: @pudaykiran I have updated my answer with a example using [jqGrid version 4.6.0](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js) and i recommend you to use this version for your desired feature

Comment: Still problem exist in jqgrid. I think the problem exist in ui.jqgrid.css file.

Comment: you should use CDN's of jqGrid instead of your local files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68202/discussion-between-pudaykiran-and-aminul).